# Make page go forward after executing JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple website which has it's pages rendered by Javascript, for example:

```
<script>
function openPage(page) {
    if(page == "Page2") document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = "You are on Page2";
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="openPage('Page2')">Page2</a>
```

This works, however my problem is that after Page2 shows up, the back button doesn't go back to the initial page. How can I make it go back to the default Page1 when the back button is pressed?

I have also tried:

```
<a href="javascript:openPage('Page2');">Page2</a>
```

But it does the same thing.

Comment: You aren't really changing pages. You are simply changing the text of the current page. If you want the back button to work, you should load a new page.

Comment: If it's an ajax app, which it looks like it, you probably have to learn about history management which is out of the scope of a single question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser's back button works on URL changes, so if the URL doesn't change, the browser assumes you are on the same page.  Luckily you can change the URL in javascript without causing a full page reload by either [setting `location.hash`](https://developers.google.com/tv/web/articles/location-hash-navigation) or by using the [html5 history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) (will only work on newer browsers). You'll have to also have some javascript to handle those events.

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have a button that change content of element with id : **page**

when you click this button you don't change the page, you change only the DOM element of the same page, this means you stay in the initial page